# karatsuba multiplcation of large numbers fails in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I've tried two versions of a karatsuba multiplcation algorithm and they both fail with different results when I test them with large X and Y values.

The parameters I'm using

```
const x = 3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592
const y = 2718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627
const solution = 8539734222673567065463550869546574495034888535765114961879601127067743044893204848617875072216249073013374895871952806582723184
```

Algorithm1 I got from this page: https://gist.github.com/haocong/c2d9b2169d28eb15a94d

```
Expected value to equal:
  8.539734222673567e+126
Received:
  7.292575034127423e+22
```

Algorithm2 I got from this page:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376023/604950

```
Expected value to equal:
  8.539734222673567e+126
Received:
  6.0002556749374185e+22
```

To reproduce you can grab this PR: 
https://github.com/Falieson/Algorithms-Illuminated-Part1_TheBasics/pull/1

Comment: Numbers are much higher than `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, they definitely won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are using numbers that are too big and JavaScript doesn't know how to handle them.

> The **Number.isSafeInteger()** method determines whether the provided value is a number that is a safe integer.
>
> 2^53 - 1 is a safe integer: it can be exactly represented, and no other integer rounds to it under any IEEE-754 rounding mode. In contrast, 2^53 is not a safe integer.
>
> console.log(warn(Math.pow(2, 53)));
>   // expected output: "Precision may be lost!"
>
> MDN

e.g. in your second algorithm you are doing

```
var res  =   (z2 *  Math.pow(10, 2 * m )  ) + ( (z1-z2-z0) * Math.pow(10,  m )) + z0;
```

which is not a safe operation in your case and JavaScript fails to compute it properly, giving you a wrong result.

If you put this code under the above mentioned line, you will see that.

```
console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(10 ** (2 * m)));
```

This evaluates to false.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why the problem, do you know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Falieson It can't be resolved. `2^53 - 1` is as far as you can go considering numeric operations in JavaScript and that is it. Beyond this limit, every numeric operation may fail and you can do nothing about it.

Comment: Here's a library that I'm going to try: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js
there's also another stackoveflow answer that references this http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber

Comment: @Falieson using a BigNum library is exactly the way to do this. Similar libraries exist for all languages without built-in infinite-precision integers. Some of those libraries already include karatsuba-like efficient multiplication...